# Does collection of all eigenvalues of $n\times n$ integer matrices form a group under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let us first define $G=\{c\mid c\text{ is eigenvalue of } A \text{ for some } A \in M_n(\Bbb{Z})\}$.
Note that, $0\in G$ (due to zero matrix) and $G\subset\Bbb{C}$ so associativity follows as hereditary property.
Now if $c\in G$, $\exists A\in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ and a non-zero vector $v\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $Av=cv$, then $(-A)v=(-c)v$ and so $-c$ is eigenvalue of $-A\in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$, so $-c\in G$.
But I cannot verify the closedness property. Although I know algebraic integers are closed under addition but **here the main problem is degree of polynomial is fixed** i.e. if we take collection of all characteristic polynomials of matrices from $M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ it will have all monic integer polynomial of degree $n$.
Can anybody check whether it is closed or not under addition? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed this set is not closed under addition. For example, for $n=2$
$$\sqrt{3} ,\sqrt{2} \in G$$
because they are eigenvalues of the matrices
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 3 \\ 1 &0
\end{matrix} \right) \qquad \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 2 \\ 1 &0
\end{matrix} \right) $$
but $\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{2} \notin G$. This is because a $2 \times 2$ matrix has characteristic polynomial of degree 2, but $\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{2}$ is not a root of a polynomial of degree 2 (with integer coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues of $n\times n$ integer matrices are algebraic of degree $\le n$. For $n=2$, we find matrices with eigenvalue $\sqrt 2$ and matrices with eigenvalue $\sqrt 3$, but not with eigenvalue $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$, which is of degree $4$.

We don't have closure under multiplication, either: For $n=3$, we have $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt[3]2$, but not their product, which is of degree $6$.